# How to use style in JavaScript without css?

Tags: javascript

**How to use style in JavaScript without css?**
I'm tring to draw shape, but there is problem with style...Please help.

Something doing wrong

```
    var Shape = function (width, height, radius) {

    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.radius = radius;

    this.drawShape = function () {
        var shape = document.createElement("div");
        document.body.appendChild(shape);
        shape.style.width = this.width;
        shape.style.height = this.height;
        shape.style.radius = this.radius;
        shape.style.border = '1px solid black'
    }
}

var shape1 = new Shape(10, 30, 30);
shape1.drawShape();
```

Comment: use jquery with .css() function

Comment: I need without jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set units, also instead of `radius` you should use `borderRadius`.

```js
var Shape = function(width, height, radius) {

  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.radius = radius;

  this.drawShape = function() {
    var shape = document.createElement("div");
    document.body.appendChild(shape);
    shape.style.width = this.width + 'px';
    shape.style.height = this.height + 'px';
    shape.style.borderRadius = this.radius + 'px';
    shape.style.border = '1px solid black'
  }
}

var shape1 = new Shape(10, 30, 30);
shape1.drawShape();
```

Comment: You're welcome, here is the same code with some ES6 https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/2647/

Comment: Happy new year!